# (C#) conditional in front end with datagrid

Tags: c#, grid, conditional-statements

I have a data grid and in that grid its making this call:

```
<ItemTemplate>                                      
<%#GroupSelectorRoleListControlExtender.GenerateGroupActuator(((GroupListItem)Container.DataItem).Id, ((GroupListItem)Container.DataItem).Name)%>
</ItemTemplate>
```

I would like to do something like this:

```
<% if (((SingleAccountGroup)Container.DataItem).Name == "blahblah") {%>
<ItemTemplate>
<%#GroupSelectorRoleListControlExtender.GenerateGroupActuator(((SingleAccountGroup)Container.DataItem).Id, ((SingleAccountGroup)Container.DataItem).Name, "portalprofile Name")%>
</ItemTemplate>
<%} %>
```

It of course doesn't work but hopefully you can see what I'm trying to do, it doesn't like that it's not bound. How can I put that conditional into a data grid like that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you might be able to use a ternary operator to make it work

```
<%#

((SingleAccountGroup)Container.DataItem).Name == "blahblah" ? 
GroupSelectorRoleListControlExtender.GenerateGroupActuator(((SingleAccountGroup)Container.DataItem).Id, ((SingleAccountGroup)Container.DataItem).Name, "portalprofile Name") : ""

%>
```

Comment: It worked but it puts an empty spot for the ones that don't equal blah blah...very close though I think.

Comment: You are going to have to have something after the else if you don't want the "empty spot".  A ternary operator reads like (condition) ? (IfTrue) : (IfFalse).  You'll notice in John's example the "IfFalse" return value is just empty string.  If you put something else there, you'll be golden.

Comment: Yeah sorry, i should have explained that a little better.